# setTimeout and closure

Tags: javascript, settimeout

Can someone explain why Eg1 works in FF but not in IE, and how come Eg2 works in both FF and IE?

### Eg1

```
// ----- works in FF, not in IE   
var msg = "Hello World";
setTimeout(doAlert, 1, msg);
function doAlert(msg)
{
    alert(msg);
}
```

### Eg2

```
// ------ works in both IE, FF
var msg = "Hello World";
setTimeout(function() {doAlert(msg);}, 1);
function doAlert(msg)
{
    alert(msg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the callback argument is not default.

To enable passing a extra parameter on IE, use this snippet:

```
    if (document.all && !window.setTimeout.isPolyfill)
      {
        var __nativeST__ = window.setTimeout;
        window.setTimeout = function (vCallback, nDelay /*, argumentToPass1, argumentToPass2, etc. */)
          {
            var aArgs = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 2);
            return __nativeST__(vCallback instanceof Function ? function ()
                                                                  {
                                                                    vCallback.apply(null, aArgs);
                                                                  } :
                                                                vCallback, nDelay
                               );
         };
      window.setTimeout.isPolyfill = true;
    }

  if (document.all && !window.setInterval.isPolyfill)
    {
      var __nativeSI__ = window.setInterval;
      window.setInterval = function (vCallback, nDelay /*, argumentToPass1, argumentToPass2, etc. */)
        {
          var aArgs = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 2);
          return __nativeSI__(vCallback instanceof Function ? function ()
                                                                {
                                                                      vCallback.apply(null, aArgs);
                                                                } :
                                                              vCallback, nDelay
                             );
        };
      window.setInterval.isPolyfill = true;
    }
```

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout